# how to reference different physical drive on linux command line

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, mountpoint

in Windows, if you have 2 physical drives using C: and D: and you're at

```
 C:\
```

you can enter:

```
 C:\ dir d:\folder1
```

to get the directory listing on the other drive. Is there an ubuntu/linux equivalent of that?

I have a computer with ubuntu 22.04 and 2 physical hard drives. If I'm in a terminal is there a way I can do an ls on the other drive "directly"?

I discovered that the other drive appears in /media/user1/myssd, but I didn't know if there's another way to reference it. I can enter

```
 $ ls -l /media/user1/myssd
```

but I wasn't sure if there is a different way to do it.

Comment: You access them via directory names, which could be just `/drive_C` and `/drive_D/` if you needed to, though I'd avoid those names if you can, as C, D etc. labels are legacy from floppy days (where A, B were floppies, C & later the hard drives; but C & D can also be partitions on the same physical drive). How you refer to drives is completely up to you (or anyone with `sudo` access to make changes). I access some network drives via `/de2900`, `/pe2900`.. as that makes sense to me.. As some *snap* software can't access that, there's also a mount in `/mnt/de2900` too that's the same. You decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first harddisk is probably mounted as the root filesystem (`/`). Run the command `df` to see where each disk is mounted.

You can use symlinks to create an "easy access" to any mounted device, in a non-intrusive way. Let's say you want a shortcut to your second harddisk `/media/user1/myssd` - you could then use the following command: (creating symlinks in root dir `/` requires sudo)

```
sudo ln -s /media/user1/myssd /hdd2
```

The path `/hdd2` is now a virtual mapping of `/media/user1/myssd`, and you can go directly to the drive by typing:

```
cd /hdd2
```

If there was a folder on `/media/user1/myssd` called `data1`, you could go there by typing:

```
cd /hdd2/data1
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: That is very helpful. I like the idea of the symlink.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, that's the way to do it. In Linux, drives are mounted at a "mount point", which just looks like another directory in your root directory tree. You can access the drive by referencing that directory (in your case, `/media/user1/myssd`, but you can mount the drive's filesystem in any directory that you want).